# Using Vector3.Distance() to only calculate distance between x axises of 2 different transforms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can I calculate the distance between 2 different objects' transform in only x axis ?

```
 float distance = Vector3.Distance(spawnPoint.transform.position, player.transform.position);
```

I use this method but the problem with  this method is that it calculates the distance between all axises of specified game objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by getting Absolute value of subtraction of vectorA x position with vectorB x position :

```
float distance = Mathf.Abs(spawnPoint.transform.position.x - player.transform.position.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, pretty mediocre but works though:

```
Vector3 g1 = new Vector3(gameObject1.transform.position.x, 0, 0);
Vector3 g2 = new Vector3(gameObject2.transform.position.x, 0, 0);
float distance = Vector3.Distance(g1,g2);
```

Comment: hehe a bit overkill ;)